# Regular expression on a remote script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a script on a remote machine (both machines use bash), using ssh, which has the following lines:

```
cd /home/invitado/
rm -r !(Desktop|Downloads|Videos|Pictures)
```

So when I run `ssh hostname './remove'`, I get this error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I tried appending this line to the script

```
shopt -s extglob
```

But I'm still having the same error, so what should I do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`shopt -s extglob` should be before `rm -r !(Desktop|Downloads|Videos|Pictures)`.

To verify, see what is the original value of `extglob` by running just `shopt`.

Note: In my case, that value was set when I run the command `rm` directly from the shell. But when I put it in script, it failed. Realized that extglob is set by default when running from interactive shell. & It is disabled by default when running inside the script.